# How to create a truststore.jks with one certificate?

Tags: certificate, c#-3.0

(I'm a newby in cryptographic things.)
I have an setup program written in C#. This asks the user to input the server URL. Then it connects to this server and stores this server certificate into a truststore file that is used by the installed Java REST service.

The truststore file is created by *keytool.exe*:

```
keytool.exe -alias anAlias -import -file cert.cer -noprompt -keystore truststore.jks -storepass aPassword
```

Now we don't want to use *keytool.exe*. We want to create the keystore by C#. My first tries are as follows:

```
class AddCertToTruststore
  {
    public static void Do()
    {
      ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += Validate;

      X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("cert.cer");
      cert.Archived = true;

      bool ok = cert.Verify(); // always false

      X509Certificate2Collection certs = new X509Certificate2Collection();
      certs.Add(cert);
      byte[] bytes = certs.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12);

      File.WriteAllBytes("truststore.jks", bytes);

      ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -= Validate;
    }

    private static bool Validate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain,
                                 SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

This code creates a truststore but I'm missing the certificate in it. If I open the truststore.jks with *KeyStore Explorer 5.1* there is not any certificate in it. What am I doing wrong?

The certificate is a self-signed certificate. `cert.Verify()` returns always `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just one line that is missing:

```
cert.FriendlyName = "anAlias";
```

It works also without the validation handler and without setting `Archived` property. So the shortest code is:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"cert.cer");
cert.FriendlyName = "anAlias";

X509Certificate2Collection certs = new X509Certificate2Collection();
certs.Add(cert);
byte[] bytes = certs.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12);

File.WriteAllBytes(@"truststore.jks", bytes);
```